# HTTP Error when trying to connect to a channel in Pubnub

Tags: android, wifi, pubnub

I am trying to connect to a channel in Pubnub using an application in Android Studio. How do I fix this?

SUBSCRIBE : ERROR on channel my_channel : [Error: 103-1] : HTTP Error. Please check network connectivity. Please contact support with error details if issue persists.

Comment: Howdy there `userRa` :-) May you paste your PubNub specific code here in your question and submit as an edit?  We can help you a bit more if we know what data is being passed into the subscribe method call.

Comment: If you can not paste code here, please submit your case to support@pubnub.com with code and we can review in private. Please reference this SO post in your email to support so we can relate it back to this post and answer here with publicly allowed information.

Answer (score 1):

Its too late to answer , but might help someone else.

Pub Nub uses internet and adding internet permissions to manifest solved my problem . This is not mentioned in pub nub documentation .

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: It is mentioned in the Android docs though. But thanks for pointing that out - would be helpful to mention it in the getting started parts of the docs. https://www.pubnub.com/docs/android-java/pubnub-java-sdk